# How to redirect ip to https domain in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I know that there's a lot of similar questions here, but none of them didn't help me, so here's my problem.

I need to redirect all requests from my server ip to my domain.

I tried the `return 301` method, it kinda worked, but got me "Too many redirects error".

It wasn't me who wrote the config originally and I'm afraid to break it, it's a live server, so I don't have much time to test things.

Here's my config:

```
    server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl;
    index index.php;
    server_name example.com;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_example_com.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_example_com.log;
    root /var/www/prod/frontend/web;
    client_max_body_size 50m;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!NULL:!RC4;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /images {
        alias /var/www/prod/frontend/web/images;
    }

    location /assets {
    expires 1d;
    }

    location /upload {
    expires 1d;
        alias /var/www/prod/frontend/web/uploads;
    }

    location /plugins/Global/scripts {
    alias /var/www/prod/frontend/web/js2;
    }

    location /plugins/Global/images {
        alias /var/www/prod/frontend/web/images;
    }

    location /plugins/Global/css {
    alias /var/www/prod/frontend/web/css;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/comn/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }


    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /var/lib/dehydrated/acme-challenges;
    }

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/dehydrated/certs/example.com/privkey.pem;
        server_name             www.example.com;


       location / {
                return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
       }

        location ~ /.git/ {
                deny all;
        }
}


server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;

    location / {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;  # enforce https
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        alias /var/lib/dehydrated/acme-challenges;
    }
}
```

Redirecting from http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to https://example.com works just fine, but I can't figure out how to get https redirecting working. What am I missing?

Also there's an admin panel to this site, it's config stored in another file, not sure if it has to be posted as well.

Comment: Make the second `server` block default, so that any `https` request which is not to `example.com` will be redirected to `example.com`. Change the `listen` statement in the second `server` block from `listen 443 ssl;` to `listen 443 ssl default_server;`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Already tried that, but it seems that nginx is ignoring the default server and going on with the first server block.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely adding this on top of my config worked, where even default_server was ignored..

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Still not sure what is wrong with my setup, but at least it's working now.

```
nginx/1.14.2
```